# Exercise 1.13 from Torchinsky's Problems in Real and Functional Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Problem 13 from Chapter 1 of Torchinsky's *Problems in Real and Functional Analysis* reads

> Let $\mathcal{A} = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} :$ the decimal expansion of $x$
>   contains every possible finite pattern of digits$\}$. Prove that
>   $\mathcal{A}$ is a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

The solution in the book follows:

> Let $d = d_1 \ldots d_n, 0 \leq d_k \leq 9$, denote a finite pattern
>   of digits; the set $\{d\}$ of all possible finite patterns is then the
>   countable union of finite sets and, hence, countable. Let $X_d$ denote
>   the set of real numbers whose decimal expansion does not contain the
>   pattern $d$; we claim that $X_d$ is nowhere dense. First, $X_d$ is
>   closed. Indeed, if $x \notin X_d$, the pattern $d$ can be found in $x$
>   and $x = x_0 x_1 \ldots x_k d_1 \ldots d_n x_{k+n+1} \ldots$, say. Let
>   $\varepsilon = 10^{-(k+n+1)}$ and note that if $|y-x| < \varepsilon$,
>   $x$ and $y$ do not differ in the first $n+k$ digits, $y$ contains the
>   pattern $d$, and so $y \in X_d^c$, which is therefore open. Next,
>   $X_d$ has empty interior. For the sake of argument suppose that there
>   are $x \in X_d$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon$
>   $) \subset X_d$; we may assume that $\varepsilon = 10^{-N}$
>   for some integer $N$. Then if the first $N$ digits of $y$ are the same
>   as those of $x$, the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than
>   $\varepsilon$. Now consider a number $y = x_0 x_1 \ldots x_N d_1 $
>   $\ldots d_n$ whose first $N$ digits are those of $x$ followed by the
>   pattern $d$. Then on the one hand $y \in (x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon$
>   $) \subset X_d$ while at the same time the decimal expansion
>   of $y$ contains the pattern $d$, which cannot happen. Thus $X_d$ is
>   nowhere dense and $X_d^c$ is open dense. Therefore $\mathcal{A} = $
>   $\cap_d X_d^c$ is the countable intersection of open dense subsets of
>   $\mathbb{R}$ and by Problem 1(b), $\mathcal{A}$ is a dense $G_\delta$
>   set in $\mathbb{R}$.

My issue is with the claim that $X_d$ is closed. Consider $d = 15$. Then, the sequence $0.14, 0.149, 0.1499, 0.14999, \ldots$ is a sequence of elements of $X_d$ that converges to $0.15$, which is certainly not in $X_d$.

More generally, if $x$ is any real number such that the pattern $d$ occurs exactly once, and subsequent digits are either all $0$ or all $9$, then any open set about $x$ contains a number whose decimal expansion does not contain the pattern $d$, so $X_d^c$ is not open.

This does not affect the argument that $X_d$ has empty interior, but it does affect the claim that $X_d$ is nowhere dense. However, I think it's pretty clear that $X_d^c$ is still dense, so the issue is showing that $X_d$ is an $F_\sigma$ set, i.e., that $X_d$ is a countable union of closed sets. This is where I'm having some difficulty.

**Question**: Can it be shown that the set $X_d$ of real numbers whose decimal expansion does not contain the finite pattern of digits $d$ is an $F_\sigma$ set?

**Clarification**: Clearly the result that $\mathcal{A}$ is a dense $G_\delta$ subset is still true, and the fix to the proof is to notice that $\cup_d \overline{X_d} = \cup_d X_d$, since every real number that has the pattern $d$ exactly once with subsequent digits either all $0$'s or all $9$'s (the elements of $\overline{X_d} \backslash X_d$ excludes some pattern, i.e., $x \in \overline{X_d} \implies x \in X_{d'}$ for some $d'$. Then, continue the proof with the $\overline{X_d}$ in place of the $X_d$.

Alternatively, you can change the quantifier in the definition of $X_d$ to be existential, i.e., $X_d$ is the set of all real numbers for which *there exists* a decimal expansion that does not contain the pattern $d$. In this interpretation, $\overline{X_d} = X_d$, and the proof continues unchanged.

However, my question is whether you can simply use the $X_d$ as defined with the universal quantifier (the set of all real numbers for which *all* decimal expansions do not contain the pattern $d$) and still continue the proof (obviously requiring more justification), without switching to $\overline{X_d}$ as above. That is, can it be shown that each $X_d$, defined with the universal quantifier, is an $F_\sigma$ set.

I feel like it should be because you've only removed a few limit points, and it would be for sure if you could show that those countably many removed points are isolated points, but they're not isolated:

> Take some pattern $d = d_1 \ldots d_k$ without any $9$'s (and not all $0$'s) and let $d' = d_1' \ldots d_k'$ be the digits of  $(\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} d_{k-j} 10^j) - 1$, where $d_1'$ is possibly $0$. Then, any open set containing $x = 0.d_1 \ldots d_k$ contains some interval $(x - 10^n, x + 10^n)$, and $y = 0.d_1' \ldots d_k' 99\ldots9 d_1 \ldots d_k$, where $d_1$ is in the $(|n| + 1)$-th place after the decimal. Then, since $d$ doesn't have any $9$'s, we know for sure that $y$ is in a neighborhood of $x$. Thus, $x$ is not isolated.

I was hoping someone else could provide better insight into whether or not the $X_d$ are $F_\sigma$ or why showing they are should be hard or impossible.

Comment: A small question: should there be a “$.$” between $x_0$ and $x_1$ in the expression $x = x_0x_1\dots x_k \dots$?

Comment: finite patern, something like periodic?

Comment: @SantanaAfton, no there does not need to be a period, since we only care about the sequence of digits. If $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x = 10^k y$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $x$ and $y$ have the same sequence of digits, and $x$ has the pattern $d$ iff $y$ has the pattern $d$. Thus, we can restrict our attention to the equivalence class $x \sim y$ iff $x = 10^k y$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, which can be represented as sequences of digits.

Comment: @user144527 That’s certainly true, but I’m mostly nitpicking about a decimal point being somewhere in the expression; without one, you’re only dealing with integers and your counterexample doesn’t hold.

Comment: @SantanaAfton, we are not dealing with only integers. The reason there is no decimal point is because where would you put it? We are not restricting ourselves to real numbers with nonzero digits only in the tens place, for instance. The numbers $149$, $14.9$, $1.49$, $0.149$, etc. all have the same sequence of digits. If $x$ is any of them, we still have $x_0 = 1$, $x_1 = 4$, $x_2 = 9$, $x_k = 0$ for $k > 2$. There is no need to put a decimal point there, and there shouldn't be one.

Comment: It's just to be exact with the equality sign. Torchinsky places a decimal point in-between $x_0$ and $x_1$ on page 171. You could be accurate in saying "The digits of $x$ are $\dots$", but the equality is fuzzy without it. If you wanted to be exactly precise, you *could* specify $x = x_{-n}\dots x_{-1}.x_0x_1\dots$.

Comment: @SantanaAfton, huh, I didn't notice the period in the book. The equality is inaccurate either way, because there are plenty of real numbers where the period is not after the first nonzero digit.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is the clause "whose decimal expansion does not contain the pattern $d$". The number $3/20$ has $two$ decimal expansions, $0.15$ and $0.14\overline 9.$ The book should say "whose  decimal expansion or expanions do not contain the pattern $d$".

Comment: Yes, you can always pick the expansion that doesn't contain the pattern to resolve the issue. Then, $X_d$ is the set of real numbers that have a decimal expansion that does not contain the pattern $d$, but I find this interpretation of the question to be unsatisfactory. Generally, people pick a convention of always terminating in either all $0$ or all $9$, and it breaks down in either case, as you see my example used the terminating in all $0$'s convention.

Comment: My question is, if you interpret $X_d$ is being "the set of real numbers in which no decimal expansion contains the pattern $d$," does the result still hold?

Comment: Yes....................................

Comment: Yes, $X_d$ is $F_\sigma$? Why?

Comment: Each $X_d$ is closed. There are only countably many finite patterns so the union of all the $X_d$ is a countable union of closed sets.

Comment: No, the $X_d$ are not closed. Did you read my post?